# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, authentication

how should I fix this error?

SecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;



@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
    this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder){
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}    

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/products","/product/show/*","/console/*","/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();

    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}


}
```

WebConfig

```
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;`
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean H2ServletRegstration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new  ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through method 'setAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

thanks! :)

Comment: is this `DaoAuthenticationProvider` implementation of `AuthenticationProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")` on your `@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService)` bean definition.

Or remove `@Qualifier` from `SecurityConfig` class, if you have single provider.